# How does IM+ poll messages from Skype

Tags: c#, chat, long-polling, skype, im+

Monitoring the requests from [IM+](https://plus.im/) while logged into a Skype account shows things like
<sub>`https://plus.im/tcp/291b26b1e4f84c07a93eb6416d72ccbe?nocache=0.23731523961760104&ack=16`</sub>
<sub>`https://plus.im/tcp/291b26b1e4f84c07a93eb6416d72ccbe/longpoll?nocache=0.23731523961760104&ack=17`</sub>

when I or someone else writes something.

I'd like to know how IM+ gets the messages from Skype, and if I can emulate the requests they make in C#, or if there is some other way of getting the messages from Skype.

Currently, I'm just listening for changes in the SQLite main.db, but it takes a few seconds after a message is sent before Skype updates it.